Cqlsh for Cassandra not working
I am using ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and it's starting giving me this error for the cqlsh:
shrivastavamahir@KnightHunter:~$ cqlsh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shrivastavamahir/.local/bin/cqlsh", line 5, in <module>
    from cqlsh.__main__ import main
  File "/home/shrivastavamahir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cqlsh/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cqlsh.cqlsh import main as cqlsh_main
  File "/home/shrivastavamahir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cqlsh/cqlsh.py", line 134, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/cluster.py", line 33, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

Can any one help me on this ?

What are the exact steps you did to produce this error. Also do you know if the cassandra driver is ready for Ubuntu 24.04 or needs updates. I can only find reference to Ubuntu 22.04 on any site referencing this driver. Suggest you contact the maker of the driver and ask them.

Just regular installation of a clean Ubuntu 24.04 and Apache Cassandra (https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html) will result in this error. The reason apparently is cqlsh not being compatible with python 3.12.+ .
